# If you have a negatively charged plastic rod, what will the direction of the electric field be?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, electricity, charge

A task by my professor includes a negatively charged rod, and he says the direction of the electric field should be in the direction of the radius of the rod--that is, outward! But we learned previously that negative charges have electric fields pointing towards them. Should a force $F=qE(r)$ between a point charge and the rod not count the electric field as in towards the rod? What am I missing?

Comment: For a finite-length rod — and what plastic rod doesn’t have finite length? — the field is neither radially inward nor outward except on the midplane. Your professor is making the infinite-length approximation when she says the field is radial.

Comment: Also it should be noted that the word radial merely implies it is parallele to the radius, it doesn't necessarily implies it points in any given direction. Though it's not uncommon to use it for the outward directed line...this is why you can have terms like radially inward and radially outward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention, the direction of the electric field is the direction of the force that a positive charge would experience if placed in the field. So the direction of the field of a negatively charged rod is radially inward.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ghoster my answer is for an infinite line of charge. In any case for a finite length rod the field is still inward at the ends